# Image history in Google Chrome

Tags: chrome

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can some image history of my browsing activities. By image history, I mean the list of images I have recently seen (vs. just giving a list of URLs on page titles)

Comment: I haven't found any extension so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.